# wp_set_auth_cookie not loggin in user to wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Below Im receiving post data via curl from another site. And logging the user in site B without password verification.
And when I check if user logged in here, it returns true. when I echo current user, it returns the one from site B databse which is correct.

But when I access site B manually or via redirect, it doesn't seem to have logged in the user.

Why so? How can I enable the user login automatically?

```
$user = $_POST;
    $a = get_user_by('login', $user['data']['user_login']);

 wp_set_current_user( $a->data->ID );
 wp_set_auth_cookie( $a->data->ID );
 do_action('wp_login', $a->data->user_login, $a);
echo site_url();
var_dump(wp_get_current_user());
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Why so? " - Because you make it to login inside CURL request, which happens in your server side - and after request is done - everything gets forgotten and cleaned.

I recommend you using one-time token logic for this purpose.
For example in A side you generate such link and redirect webpage to that:  http://B/?auth_token=SOME_CRYPTED_TOKEN_HERE

SOME_CRYPTED_TOKEN_HERE - is some encrypted information and contains user ID, login etc.

In B side write simple script which checks

```
if (isset($_GET["auth_token"])) {
 //do some decrypt here and check if auth_token is valid, and after decryption use ID and login to make auth
 wp_set_current_user( $ID );
 wp_set_auth_cookie( $ID );
 do_action('wp_login', $LOGIN);
}
```

I hope the idea is clear.